# PHP Telegram bot API. editMessageReplyMarkup returns false

Tags: php, bots, telegram

I have a question about using editMessageReplyMarkup method in Telegram bot API in PHP.

I'm trying to provide user choose category and sub-category after with **InlineKeyboardMarkup** . But I want to make it with replacing one Keyboard with another.

I found method **[editMessageReplyMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup)**  which does exectly what I need , but for some reason it returns me false. 
On the first screenshot you can see how bot sends me categories. 
[image: choosing between categories]

After I choose any of it next code is running:

```
if (is_array($update[count($update)-1]["callback_query"])) {
    $chat_id = $update[count($update)-1]["callback_query"]["from"]["id"];
    $requested_category = $update[count($update)-1]["callback_query"]['data'];
    $message_answer_id = $update[count($update)-1]["callback_query"]['message']['message_id'];
    send_sub_projects($user_model, $telegram, $chat_id, $requested_category, $message_answer_id);
}
```

Here is the method **send_sub_projects**

```
function send_sub_projects($user_model, $telegram, $chat_id, $category, $message_id) {

   $subcategories = $user_model->get_sub_categories($category);
   for ($i=0; $i < count($subcategories); $i++) { 
      $subcategories[$i] = 
      array(array('text'=>$subcategories[$i],'callback_data'=>$subcategories[$i]));
   }
   $decoded_subcategories = json_encode(array('inline_keyboard' => $subcategories));

   $parameters = 
       array(
           'chat_id' => $chat_id, 
           'message_id' => $message_id,
           'reply_markup' => $decoded_subcategories
       );
   $telegram->editMessageReplyMarkup($parameters)
}
```

So basically I send everything which is requeired: message_id, chat_id, new_markup. And when I run that script I can see arrays are built fine, see the next screenshot:
[image: built array]

And everything I got from this is false returning me from method I called, of coruse no changes in telegram bot message.

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you for reply.

Comment: The code you shared doesn't make any sense.